# Caching on IIS for every client

Tags: asp.net, caching, iis

I have an asp.net application where I am using 5 queries that executed in every pages. What I wanted to do is I want to execute the query and cache it to the IIS server as list of objects. This cached items will be there in IIS and any client hits the server from any location or any session scope that cached items (resides in IIS) will be returned. There is no need to execute the SQL query on the DB every time even the request comes from the different client. I am not using ASP.Net MVC this is traditional asp.net.

Is there any solution for it. Please guide me, waiting for reply. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your framework version ? Did you try using the caching objects ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use caching or static class. I prefer static class to hold cached values since it gives me more control. You can create a static class in App_code call it cachedvalues.cs

```
public static class cachedvalues
{
public static string value1="";
Public static getvalue1()
{
 if(value1=="")
 value1 = initializevalue();
}
return value1;
}
```

create a variable value1 to hold the cached value, and create a method to access the value, this method will initialize the value if it is not initialized.

Comment: I have gone through your details, but the problem is parameter will be different, so I don't know how much variable needs to be declared.